# Error on implementing spring-saml-security with WSO2

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am trying to implement SAML 2.0 is my application, by using my app as a service provider and WSO2 server as an idp. I have downloaded and implemented the spring-security-saml2-sample application and I have modified it to work with WSO2 server as idp and the sample application works as expected.

I am now trying to incorporate securityContext.xml and the related configurations into my application, however I am getting an exception during metadata generation.

The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Manager with name 'MetadataKeyInfoGenerator' does not exist
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager.getFactory(NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager.java:157)
    at org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityHelper.getKeyInfoGenerator(SecurityHelper.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateKeyInfoForCredential(MetadataGenerator.java:255)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.getServerKeyInfo(MetadataGenerator.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.buildSPSSODescriptor(MetadataGenerator.java:329)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateMetadata(MetadataGenerator.java:189)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

My securityContext.xml metadata config is as follows

```xml
<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/c/success.jsp"/>
</bean>
<!--
Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
   <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
</bean>
-->

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error-handler.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:saml20:sso"/>
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
<bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/wso2-idp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>         
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I have not made any major changes to the sample applications securityContext.xml. Has anyone encountered any similar errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please find below my entire securityContext.xml

```
<!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

<!-- Unsecured pages 
<security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
<security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>-->

<!-- Security for the administration UI 
<security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" access-denied-page="/saml/web/metadata/login">
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
</security:http>-->

<!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
<security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/c/auth/INB"/>
</bean>
<!--
Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
   <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
</bean>
-->

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error-handler.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:saml20:ssomanager"/>
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
<bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/wso2-idp.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>         
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
    <!--
    <property name="userDetails" ref="bean" />
    -->
</bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
<bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
<bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
            <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
            <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
            <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="processor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

<!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
<bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
    <property name="builderFeatures">
        <map>
            <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
```

I have included SAMLBootstrap in the context.xml

Answer (score 5):

Might be helpful for others. I faced similar issue and the reason this occurred was that another piece of legacy code in the system was re-instantiating OpenSAML library by invoking `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();`

Since SpringSAML already initializes it during container bootstrapping, had to remove initialization from legacy code

Answer (score 2):

Having the complete `securityContext.xml` in your question would really help. But first of all make sure it contains the following bean, as the exception seems to indicate that the initialization login in SAML bootstrap wasn't executed:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>
```

Also, try changing the bean to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap" lazy-init="false"/>
```

Comment: I have edited my post with the entire securityContext.xml. The only difference with the sample project is that I am not building with Maven, so I have not added a dependency in the pom.xml. Instead I have added spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar and the related jars to my classpath. I am building my project with ant. So this exception may be a classpath related issue. I am trying now to compare my classpath with the sample projects to see if I have missed something.

Comment: Updated response with another idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! I finally got it to work by tweaking the sample applications generated metadata, saving it and modifying the Extendedmetadata bean to access sp metadata from classpath. I am running into signature validation issues now. Hopefully I can fix those and then try your solution.