# springSAML 'MetadataKeyInfoGenerator' does not exist

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I recently encountered a problem with using springSAML 2.0 in a java project. The "problem" looks very "simple". I also tried to consult the literature and follow the tips on the article but it still does not work.

The network environment in which my program is located is very complex because it is a commercial system for the company. Therefore, the java program is deployed under F5 load balancing. I have already paid attention to setting the class of "contextProvider" to "SAMLContextProviderLB", but the problem It should not be here.

I checked it out: 
[Error on implementing spring-saml-security with WSO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638265/error-on-implementing-spring-saml-security-with-wso2)

I've set:  to **lazy-init = false**, but it still does not work.

I also checked: 
[SAML authentication is failing with 'MetadataKeyInfoGenerator' does not exist after enabling AXIS2 #200](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/200)

Although I also suspect that Axis2.0 problem, but I do have no evidence of this problem.

I have two machines deployed two java applications, and these two java applications are open springSAML function, of course, I have generated a keystore configured correctly (but I use the same two keystore two applications, because I The configuration is exactly the same), the two machines after I stop and then start I visit samlLogin are ok, and then I found a customer complained after sleeping, said idp select interface appeared 500 errors, I looked found:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Manager with name 'MetadataKeyInfoGenerator' does not exist
org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager.getFactory (NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager.java:156)
org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityHelper.getKeyInfoGenerator (SecurityHelper.java:1049)
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateKeyInfoForCredential (MetadataGenerator.java:255)
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.getServerKeyInfo (MetadataGenerator.java: 211)
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.buildSPSSODescriptor (MetadataGenerator.java:329)
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.generateMetadata (MetadataGenerator.java:189)
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.processMetadataInitialization (MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:127)
org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter (MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:86)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy $ VirtualFilterChain.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal (FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter (FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
```

I know this question is DefaultBootstrap does not seem to start, I do not know when Spring will start it, I tracked the source found because:

```
public class NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager
{
  private Map <String, KeyInfoGeneratorManager> managers;
```

There's nothing inside the managers.
I was thinking why the managers could not find 'MetadataKeyInfoGenerator'.

Please help me.

**my java project web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SSO</display-name>
  <!--分割线|在启用saml模式下打开配置|start -->
   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/securityContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param> 
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
   <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/saml/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/samlLogin</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
           <!--  分割线|在启用saml模式下打开配置 |end-->
  ......
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoggingConfigure</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ztesoft.zsmart.web.util.Log4jConfigServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
      <param-value>CVBS_WEBAPP_REALPATH</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet> 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MVCServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MVCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MVCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oauth/2.0/authorize/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MVCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oauth/2.0/token/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MVCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oauth/2.0/token/validate/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MVCServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/oauth/2.0/user/getInfo/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>WebInitServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WebInitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ztesoft.zsmart.sso.web.servlet.WebInitServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>DEFAULT_LANGUAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>en-US</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>LOCAL_CHARSET</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>DEFAULT_CHARSET</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>REQUEST_ENCODE</param-name>
      <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!--  saml 功能开启是打开-->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>samlLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           com.ztesoft.zsmart.sso.web.servlet.SamlLoginServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>  
           <param-name>serviceUrl</param-name>  
           <param-value>/saml/logout</param-value>  
        </init-param>
        <init-param>  
           <param-name>path</param-name>  
           <param-value>/</param-value>  
        </init-param>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>samlLoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/samlLogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <description>Common Servlet for Download</description>
    <display-name>Common Servlet for Download</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ztesoft.zsmart.web.servlet.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DownloadServlet.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LoginIndex.do</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/Error.do?SSO_ERROR_CODE=S-SSO-10044</location>
  </error-page>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>OauthAppAPI</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OauthAppAPI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ztesoft.zsmart.sso.oauth.v2.as.api.OauthAppAPI</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OauthAppAPI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OauthAppAPI</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**my securityContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <!-- 配置不拦截资源 -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/webportal/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/webtechfrm/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/sso/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/oauth/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/*.do"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/*/*/*.do"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/*/*/*/*.do"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/Login.jsp*"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/metadata/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/services/**"/>

    <!--配置节点 -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint" use-expressions="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
        <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!--SAML处理拦截器-->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
            <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
        </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/samlLogin"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
    <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/Error.do?SSO_ERROR_CODE=P_ADFS_LOGINERROR"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
        <!--<property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/LoginIndex.do"/>-->
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
        <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

    <!-- 配置SSL证书，需要在部署之前配置好 -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/tomcat/tomcat-ssl.keystore"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="ztesoft"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="tomcat7" value="ztesoft"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="tomcat7"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
        <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
                <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
                <!--  
                <property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
                -->
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
        <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/idpSelection.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 该过滤器希望对已配置的URL进行调用，并向用户提供表示该应用程序部署的SAML2元数据。 -->
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="extendedMetadata">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
            <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
        </property>
            <property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://webportalapp.bes.post.lu:8440/sso"/>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- 配置IDP Metadata，可配置多个 -->
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <!-- ADFS -->
                 <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource">
                                    <constructor-arg value="/sso/cer/post/federationmetadata.xml"/>
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>

    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <!--<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>-->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB">
     <property name="scheme" value="https"/>
     <property name="serverName" value="webportalapp.bes.post.lu"/>
     <property name="serverPort" value="8440"/>
     <property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="false"/>
     <property name="contextPath" value="/sso"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
        <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
                <ref bean="postBinding"/>
                <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
                <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
                <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="processor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                        <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
        <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 初始化 OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap" lazy-init="false"/>

    <!-- 初始化搜索引擎 -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>


    <!--  OpenSAML解析所需的XML解析器池-->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize"/>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: I analyzed this with our system architect, who speculated that System I successfully started bootstrap and that Machine II failed to start up, so a 500 error occurred when the load was balanced on Machine II.

Unfortunately, we used to have all the logs for spring closed for performance problems, so logs were not caught when the problem occurred, and the input problem did not show up overnight. I am now trying to shut down the machine I and restart the machine II. I hope to encounter a 500 error reappear, and then I can find it in the machine log 2: Error invoking OpenSAML bootstrap